# Startup script for brightness

Tags: command-line, scripts, brightness, xrandr

Not so long ago I replaced XP for Lubuntu 14.04 on a old PC, and it works great. To make it perfect, I want to autoexecute "xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness 1" on startup or boot. Thereby not having to do it manual............ everytime. Using the internet, I was thinking of using the following:

```
vi file.sh
cp file.sh /xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness 1/init.d/file.sh
chmod +x /xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness 1/init.d/file.sh
sudo update-rc.d file.sh start 99 2 .
sudo update-rc.d -f file.sh remove
```

But at the second commandline I receive the error: "E486 pattern not found". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntactical issues with the code you've posted but that's not the main issue here.

The problem with the low-level `init` systems like `update-rc.d` (et al) is they'll run before X has started. Even in event systems like Upstart where you can wait for `starting-x`, you're still outside the X environment and you lack things like the `DISPLAY` variable. That's obviously a huge issue for things like `xrandr` where you *need* an X server.

Thankfully X (or I should say the script that loads X) will look for an `~/.xsession` file when it starts. This is a perfect place to lodge commands like this. It has to be executable and contain a proper launch stanza. We can do all of this in one command:

```
install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin ~/.xsession << EOF
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness
EOF
```

Just paste that in and it should create the file. Next time you log in, it should run.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line, you are copying `file.sh` to `/xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness 1/init.d/file.sh`. That's NOT a folder. That's a command. You cant copy to a command. Probably you want the command IN `file.sh` and then copy that to somewhere? 
In the third line you make the same mistake. You're chmodding a COMMAND, not a file or folder. That again is impossible.

What you probably want to do is:

```
echo "/xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 3:3:3 --brightness 1" > file.sh
cp file.sh /to/wherever/it/needs/to/be
chmod +x /to/wherever/it/needs/to/be/file.sh
```